# Change logical interface name based on driver not MAC address?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I have a usb to ethernet adapter that gets set as eth1.  I can easily change this in 70-persistant-net.rules and name it how I like.  This is based on the MAC address though.  I have tons of these USB adapters and I want it to change to a specific name no matter which one I plug in.  Each one has a different MAC address so if I plug in a different one it doesn't get changed to what I want.  Only 1 will be plugged in at a time so duplicate names won't happen.

Is there a way to change the interface name based on something other than MAC address so that no matter which one I plug in, it will always say in my case bac0.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got this to work.  This is what I had to use in the 70-persistant file.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="bac0"
```

the ATTRS is what did it I think.  I don't even know what that is and how it worked lol.  I'll take it though.  I can now plug in different usb to ethernet adapters and each one gets the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're selecting the device by MAC like this

```
[...]ATTR{address}=="57:04:b6:c2:6c:z3"[...]
```

You might try selecting by vendor and model instead

```
[...]ATTR{vendor}=="VENDOR", ATTR{model}=="MODEL"[...]
```

The necessary information can be obtained from `lsusb` or via `udevadm`.

I have not tried this myself, so it is only a somewhat educated guess on my end.

Comment: the top of the 70-persistant file says not to change anything but the name.   Everytime I try to change anything else my networking breaks on reboot.